# Induction of disease

Tags: immunology

In the paper they are infection WT and IL-22-/- mice with C rodentium on some occasions they use oral infection, on others they use IV and on some they use a bacteremia model. Can anyone please clarify why they may have done this?

Comment: Please provide a link to the paper you are referring to. Have you any ideas why they have done this? Any suggestions? You may be right or wrong and that way we can explain it, rather than provide answers without a context for you. Typically this may be done out of experimental limitations (time of onset, stage of disease, strength of induction, or age of animal, etc.), or to show that a treatment efficacy holds independent of the method of induction, since the methods are not created equal, i.e. multiple lines of evidence are stronger than a single kind of attempt.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! In addition to following the suggestions from @SPr, please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. ——— In particular, your title should give a better sense of what you are asking. In addition, please improve your posts clarity — the grammar and lack of punctuation make parsing your first sentence difficult (e.g. I'm guessing infection should have been infecting). Finally it is best to spell out the bacterial genus and define abbreviations like IV. Thanks! 